# Selecting all the records that a flag is not set

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

How do I find all the `bookingNo` where the `hasPaid` flag is not set to 0?

Cannot get it to work. I should get booking 2-4-8 with the `HasPaid` flag is not set to 1

Many thanks

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#testFlag') is not null
        drop table #testFlag

    create table #testFlag (BookingNo int,  HasPaid bit)


    insert into #testFlag (BookingNo, HasPaid)
      select 1, 0 union ALL
      select 1, 1 union ALL
      select 2, 0 union ALL
      select 3, 0 union ALL
      select 3, 1 union ALL
      select 3, 0 union ALL
      select 4, 0 union ALL
      select 4, 0 union ALL
      select 4, 0 union ALL  
      select 5, 0 union ALL
      select 5, 1 union ALL
      select 6, 0 union ALL
      select 6, 1 union ALL
      select 7, 0 union ALL
      select 7, 1 union ALL
      select 8, 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with a `CASE` based `HAVING` like this.

**Query**

```
  SELECT BookingNo FROM #testFlag
  GROUP BY BookingNo
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN HasPaid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

**Output**

```
BookingNo
2
4
8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select BookingNo 
  from #testFlag  
except
select BookingNo 
  from #testFlag 
 where HasPaid = 1
```

[except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

If you want to use group by then

```
SELECT BookingNo FROM #testFlag
 GROUP BY BookingNo
HAVING MAX(cast(HasPaid as int)) = 0;
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, how is that different from just doing "select BookingNo from #testFalg where HasPaid <> 1".  Seems simpler that way.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Out of curiosity why don't you test.  Does your simpler way return booking 2-4-8?

Comment: Nope, guess not :-)  I only read the first sentence of the question "How do I find all the bookingNo where the hasPaid flag is not set to 0?".  Sorry about that.

Comment: Note, that we have two `table scans` here.

Comment: @gotqn So, two table scans.  It works and is easy to follow.

Comment: @Blam I like using `except` and `intersect` too. Just pointed that it is not efficient when large amount of data is proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with duplicated BookingNo. 
If you want to choose all BookingNo where HasPaid is not 0 try this:

```
  select distinct BookingNo from #testFlag t1 where HasPaid != 0
  and not exists (select 1
  from #testFlag t2 where HasPaid = 0 and t2.BookingNo = t1.BookingNo
  )
```

If you want to choose all BookingNo where HasPaid is not 1 try this:

```
  select distinct BookingNo from #testFlag t1 where HasPaid != 1
  and not exists (select 1
  from #testFlag t2 where HasPaid = 1 and t2.BookingNo = t1.BookingNo
  )
```